# Pass a variable to decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber, nsuinteger

Forgive me if I use the wrong terminology as I'm still a little new at iOS development. I've built a calculator-type app and I want users to be able to control how numbers are rounded. Here's the code I'm using:

```
-(NSString*)calculateWidthFromHeightString:(NSString*)height usingDimensions:(Favorite*)dimensions{

int decimalPlaces = [self.userData.rounding intValue];

NSUInteger *roundingMethod;
if ([self.userData.roundingMode isEqualToString:@"up"]) {
  roundingMethod = NSRoundUp;
}
else if ([self.userData.roundingMode isEqualToString:@"plain"]) {
    roundingMethod = NSRoundPlain;
}
else {
    roundingMethod = NSRoundDown;
}

NSDecimalNumberHandler *handler = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:roundingMethod
scale:decimalPlaces
raiseOnExactness:NO
raiseOnOverflow:NO
raiseOnUnderflow:NO
raiseOnDivideByZero:NO];
```

This works as expected, but I'm getting the following compiler warning where I assign the rounding mode to the pointer "roundingMethod":

> Incompatible Integer to pointer conversion assigning to ‘NSUInteger *’
>   (aka ‘unassigned long *) from ‘NSUInteger’ (aka ‘unassigned long’)
>   Incompatible Integer to pointer conversion assigning to ‘NSUInteger *’
>   (aka ‘unassigned int *) from ‘NSUInteger’ (aka ‘unassigned int’)

I don't really know what this means. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the asterisk. NSUInteger is not a class.

Comment: Oh, jeez! That did it. Thank you so much, Maddy! I feel pretty silly now. This is my first question so I'm not sure how to mark something as the answer. It doesn't appear as though I can do that with your comment. Are you able to answer in a different way that I can mark so you get the points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
NSUInteger *roundingMethod;
```

should be:

```
NSUInteger roundingMethod;
```

`NSUInteger` is a native type, not a class type.

Comment: Thanks again, Maddy. :)